# CakePHP (2.0) Dynamic URLs

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I'm currently looking into CakePHP 2.0 and wanting to convert old 1.3 projects to 2.0. I'm going to start from scratch because there's a whole lot of code in the projects that could  be a lot better.

One of those things is the dynamic URLs, the projects multilingual and even the URLs change to the chosen language. Eg:

English: `/pages/new-article`
Dutch: `/paginas/nieuw-artikel`

Both would go to `PagesController::display();`

Note: the URLs can be way longer, pages can have subpages and those will be added to the URL too. Eg: `/pages/new-article/article-subpage`

Now, the way I did it before is to have a route for everything going to a specific action. Like * going to `PagesController::index();`

However this seems to slow the apps down and it brings a lot of problems along with it.

So my question to you is, is there a simpler way to do this?

I do not want to hardcode anything, I should be able to change `/pages/article` to `/page/article` without needing to change the code.

Note: If you know a way to do it in 1.2 or 1.3, that would also be great, 2.0 isn't that different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well i figured it out, apparently CakePHP 1.3 and 2.0 allow you to create custom route classes. It's in the documentation here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html?highlight=route#custom-route-classes

So basically what you need to do is create a file `APP/Lib/Routing/Route/UrlRoute.php` with the following contents:

```
class UrlRoute extends CakeRoute{

    public function parse($url){
        $params = parent::parse($url);

        # Here you get the controller and action from a database.

        // tmp
        $params['controller'] = 'pages';
        $params['action'] = 'index';

        return $params;
    }
}
```

And in your `APP/Config/routes.php` you put the following:

```
App::import('Lib', 'Routing/Route/UrlRoute');
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'index'), array('routeClass' => 'UrlRoute'));
```

I think the real challenge is getting the arguments that usually get passed to the functions back to work. `func_get_args()` now returns everything behind the domain name. And retrieving the URL from the database if you're using extra params. Might have to cache each URL.